# Envoy proxy standard_init_linux.go:228

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apple-m1, envoyproxy

I am trying to spinup a envoy proxy on aks cluster and getting following error on the pod

```html
kubectl logs api-gateway-6b7875b58c-6m62h  
W1019 16:55:46.464787   15617 azure.go:92] WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.26+; use https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin instead.
To learn more, consult https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

```html
kubectl describe pod api-gateway-6b7875b58c-6m62h  
W1019 17:10:56.983086   16532 azure.go:92] WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.26+; use https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin instead.
To learn more, consult https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
Name:             api-gateway-6b7875b58c-6m62h
Namespace:        namespace
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             aks-k8spool-33070793-vmss00000c/10.15.90.16
Start Time:       Wed, 19 Oct 2022 15:14:53 -0400
Labels:           app=api-gateway
                  pod-template-hash=6b7875b58c
Annotations:      kubernetes.io/limit-ranger:
                    LimitRanger plugin set: cpu, memory request for container api-gateway; cpu, memory limit for container api-gateway
Status:           Running
IP:               172.x.x.x
IPs:
  IP:           172.x.x.x
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/api-gateway-6b7875b58c
Containers:
  api-gateway:
    Container ID:   containerd://90d2fb5412f54705fadde1656bd984e93a3d4fb851b6e2d0ca3f6c5343e9813d
    Image:          mck-ontada-sre.jfrog.io/g2-proxy/api-gateway:2.0-arm64
    Image ID:       mck-ontada-sre.jfrog.io/g2-proxy/api-gateway@sha256:3786bc52191e127848b80b00d7edcbf4d4103ca7a030c86f2b3d946df7b2ef2f
    Ports:          8080/TCP, 8001/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Wed, 19 Oct 2022 17:08:05 -0400
      Finished:     Wed, 19 Oct 2022 17:08:05 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  27
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  512M
    Requests:
      cpu:        250m
      memory:     256M
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-s7bks (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-s7bks:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  55s (x534 over 115m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

the pod is going through the crashloopbackoff

```html
kubectl get pods  
W1019 17:02:08.682749   16033 azure.go:92] WARNING: the azure auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.26+; use https://github.com/Azure/kubelogin instead.
To learn more, consult https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
api-gateway-6b7875b58c-6m62h            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   25 (4m16s ago)   107m
```

Here is the docker file which is built on Mac M1 chip

```html
FROM envoyproxy/enoy-dev:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq install --no-install-recommends -y curl \
    && apt-get -qq autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY ./envoy.yaml /etc/envoy.yaml
RUN chmod go+r /etc/envoy.yaml
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/envoy", "-c", "/etc/envoy.yaml", "--service-cluster", "mcpx-gateway"]
```

I have rebuilt the image using this command to eliminate any issues because of the different architecture of M1 chip

```html
docker build --platform=linux/arm64 -t api-gateway:2.0-arm64 .
```

I am pulling image from the jfrog artifactory

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the issue was docker image was created on apple m1 and that was resolved by building the image with --platform for amd64